# Calculation of series circuit elements

Tags: voltage, power-electronics, schematics, amperage, physics

I have a series circuit. Should it be true for this series circuit if I true to write like:

```
I(R1) + I(C) = I(R2,L)

I(R1) = (U(in) - U(out)) / R1
I(C) = C(d(U(in) - U(out))) / dt
I(R2, L) = U(out) / (R2 + X(L))
```

I don't understand enoght how to get `I(R2, L)`

[image]

Comment: I think you mean "series" instead of "chain."

Comment: Yes, I edited, thanks

Comment: @aleksandr in this context the word `series` is an adjective, like the word `red` ... you would not say `I have a red` ... in your question, you are referring to a circuit ... `I have some series circuit` ... or `I have a series circuit`

Comment: Thanks! I did not known about it

Comment: Can you assume the load on the output always has high impedance (i.e., much higher than \$R_2 + j\omega L\$)?

Comment: Also, is it intentional that there is a wire shown shorting the input? If that wire is present, I(R2, L) is always zero, because the input is shorted (assuming there's no power being back-fed from the output port).

Comment: Do you want use differential equations or Laplace functions ?

Comment: I used differential equations

Comment: Another issue: You use `U2` as a variable in your last equation, but you haven't defined what voltage this refers to in your diagram. Did you mean to have \$U_{out}\$ there instead of U2?

Comment: Yes, I mean ```U(out)```

Comment: Please edit your question post to use a consistent set of names for the different variables.

Comment: I edited, thanks

Comment: The voltage arrows and current arrows are not compatible with the equations.

Comment: Should the current arrow be in the opposite direction?

Comment: @aleksandr can you write a specific question?